# conditional within four units

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, conditional-statements

I'm not using my conditional statements correctly and don't know if I need a while loop or for loop instead of what I am attempting.  What my code wishes to do is to look at the `tl` or `bl` value the previous four rows and if `tl > Upper` or `bl < Lower` then we need to make sure that `(current_row['difference'] > 0) & (row_minus1['difference'] < 0)`.

First step is to check the `or` statements, meaning `row_minus1['tl'] > Upper or...row_minus4['tl'] > Upper...or row_minus4['bl'] < Lower`, and then check the `(current_row['difference'] > 0) & (row_minus1['difference'] < 0)` condition.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    # do something
    current_row = data.iloc[i,:]
    row_minus1 = data.iloc[i-1,:]
    row_minus2 = data.iloc[i-2,:]
    row_minus3 = data.iloc[i-3,:]
    row_minus4 = data.iloc[i-4,:]

    if ((current_row['difference'] > 0) & (row_minus1['difference'] < 0)) & 
      (((row_minus1['tl'] > Upper) or (row_minus1['bl'] < Lower) )) or
      ((row_minus2['tl'] > Upper) or (row_minus2['bl'] < Lower) )) or 
      ((row_minus3['tl'] > Upper) or (row_minus3['bl'] < Lower) )) or
      ((row_minus4['top_line'] > Upper) or (row_minus4['bl'] < Lower) ))) :
```

Comment: You are using `&` in a context where you probably mean `and` (probably not the issue, but it is a coding infelicity if nothing else)

Comment: What is the actual operation you are looking to do in this function? If it's vectorisable, there may not be a need to loop through your data one row at a time.

Comment: the rows are being populated real time, not sure if that makes a difference.  I dont think the rows are vectorizable. I did not realize 'and' and '&' were different, I have not used python much.  Not sure what you mean by actual operation or how that differs from what I stated the goals are, bit confused there

Comment: What comes *after* the if statement ?

Comment: What do you expect when `i` is small and `i - 4` is beyond your array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your question, what is actually wrong.

First. I think you have a problem with the number of brackets in your first line with if

```
if ((current_row['difference'] > 0) & (row_minus1['difference'] < 0))
```

open - open - close - open - close - close

3 - 3 = 0. So the last closed barcket makes an error

Second. There is a logical problem if i<3. Say i=0, so you get data.iloc[0-1]. I suppose that is not what you want. If you want to skip first 4 items, you can just change first line with

```
for i in range(4, len(data)):
```

In this case you wouldn't have a problem with negative index.

Third. In python `&` is a bitwise and. For boolean values it works OK, but it is better to replace with `and`.

Forth. You can simplify the condition check, using vector to scalar comparison

```
data.iloc[i-4:i].loc[:, 't1'] > Upper
```

This will give you a Series of True|False values. You need to check if any of this is True, which is done by `.any()`

Fifth. In python variable names start with lower case, so better rename your variables to `lower, upper`

So we come down to that code

```
for i in range(4, len(data)):
    current_row = data.iloc[i, :]
    previous_row = data.iloc[i-1, :]

    if ((current_row['difference'] > 0) and
        (previous_row['difference'] < 0) and (
            (data.iloc[i-4:i].loc[:, 'tl'] > upper).any() or
            (data.iloc[i-4:i].loc[:, 'bl'] < lower).any())):
        do_what_you_need
```

Comment: Thank you.  that gives me something I can play with